# Android SparseArray remove

Tags: android, sparse-matrix

I have favorite list;

```
private static SparseArray<MFavori> liste = new SparseArray<>();
```

And i store this sharedpreferencefiles;

```
myactivity()
        .getSharedPreferences("favori", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
        .putString(String.valueOf(key), new Gson().toJson(value))
        .apply();
```

But when i remove object on my favorite list after save sharedpreference. Load after then i show deleting keys(because sparse array remove code doesnt remove keys) and this keys have empty values > {}...

I was debug my application and i show this;

**Before deleting sparsearray i show two keys and two values (its normal)**

[image: Before deleting]

**But when i was remove object in my favorite list i show this picture;**

```
liste.remove(keyID);
```

After this code remove value but i show already store key. Why? Its problem for my because when save this list with gson after load i show empty data{} but have key so its problem for me..

[image: After deleting]

Sory for my bad english..

Comment: What's keyID in your call to remove()?  Can you show more code?  I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: at first list have two items 10391 and 10392. when i was remove id with > list.remove(10392); and debug i show second screen. 10392 keys already storing but values removing (key dont removing).

Comment: Is it important to keep your items sorted by this id?  If not, could you use a HashMap instead, which might be better suited for this use?

Comment: its important for my because i store sparsearray with Gson to sharedpreference. When refresh my favorite list and load sharedpreference with gson, i show deleted keys with empty values

Comment: You can use gson with hasmap as well.  It's probably even better that way.

Comment: yes bro probably i use hashmap...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is working as expected. The source of `SparseArray.remove()` resets the value of the item mapped to 'keyID' with a default object and sets a flag to indicate that garbage collection is required. The documentation doesn't say anything about removing the key as well as the value. From the delete method called by `SparseArray.remove()`:

```
/**
 * Removes the mapping from the specified key, if there was any.
 */
public void delete(int key)
```